# Excel cell value not showing when writing

Tags: microsoft-excel

Excel Version: `15.41(171205)` 
Operating System: `macOS 11.0 Beta`

When I write a text on a cell, the text does not appear on the actual cell but appears on the function tab.
 After I type some value and press `enter`, the text appears normally.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZPiO.png)

How do I fix this so that I can edit a cell directly, not via the function tab?

I tried some methods from the web to solve the problem—

- I did `right click` -> `Format Cells` but my format is not `;;;` [Link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_winother-mso_2010/excel-text-not-showing/c97a7c4a-ae43-479b-9bd6-c9814549ea54)
- I went `view` but I can't find `Arrange all` and `Tiled` [Link](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/1195388-text-is-invisible-when-typing-into-certain-cells.html)

How do I make cells display value?

Comment: Welcome to superuser.com! In case you find an answer to help solve a problem don't forget to click either the grey ☑ or the up-pointing arrow/triangle to the left of the text.

Answer (score 0):

**First option**

Look into Excel settings
find `Edit cell content in cell` *(or similar)*
set it to Yes/True/Ticked
*(from memory, cannot check, no excel available currently)*

---

**Second thing to try?**

Reset all preferences:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/975724/excel-for-mac-error-the-application-microsoft-excel-quit-unexpectedly

Comment: It is currently checked right now, but I cannot see my text inside the cell still.

Comment: updated with a more (destructive) option..

Comment: First of all, thank you for your response. I did follow your steps, but it doesn't seem to work... I tried to check `Edit cell content in cell` and it was already checked somehow. Nevertheless, when I try to write a text on a cell, the text does not appear on the cell as it did before. I feel like this is the bug

Comment: When I first installed my Excel, it exactly worked like this. I have never seen Microsoft Excel working properly.

Comment: Well, I'm out of ideas; unless you have more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a new Workbook and test with the same behavior in Excel. If this issue still existed, you can troubleshoot Office for Mac issues by completely uninstalling before you reinstall:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot-office-for-mac-issues-by-completely-uninstalling-before-you-reinstall-ec3aa66e-6a76-451f-9d35-cba2e14e94c0?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US